# How can I go back to the previous page like it was before with all the data and options that were selceted

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I am still new to angular. I was working on a feature where the user selects data in a certain part of the page and then clicks a button which redirects them to another page with the data selected. Now I am trying to make a go back button which returns you to the previous page how it was before I routed to the next page with all the data and selected data that was previously there.

When I look around most people are saying use one of these methods

```
goBack(){
window.history.back();
} 

goBack(){
window.history.back();
} 

goBack(){
this.router.navigate(['path'])
}
```

however when I do this it reverts me back to the previous page without any of the data like a clean refresh.

Is there an easy way to go back to the previous page like how it was before I routed to a new place.

Thank you I really appreciate any help I am on angular version 13.2.3

Answer (score 1):

With you requirement, `ReuseRoutingStrategy` will suited with this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular13-bootstrap-thlnn7)

The origin component won't be destroy while you routed to other route.
which mean, everything still be there even value in form input and also `ngOnDestroy` won't active as well.

**How to**

1. Modify provider of `RouteReuseStrategy` in **app.module.ts**

   ```
   providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: ReuseRoutingStrategy }]
   ```
2. Implement `ReuseRoutingStrategy`

   ```
   export class ReuseRoutingStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
     storedHandles: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

     shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
       return route.data.reuseRoute || false;
     }

     store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
       if (route.data.reuseRoute) {
         this.storedHandles[route.data.reuseKey] = handle;
       }
     }

     shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
       const handle = this.storedHandles[route.data.reuseKey];
       return !!route.routeConfig && !!handle;
     }

     retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
       const id = route.data.reuseKey;
       if (!route.routeConfig || !this.storedHandles[id]) {
         return null;
       }

       return this.storedHandles[id];
     }

     shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
       return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add `data` to your route config to told which page you like to make it remembered
   (`reuseKey` is unique key for your specific each route which use the same component.)

   ```
   {
       path: '',
       data: { reuseRoute: true, reuseKey: 'some_key' },
       component: MainComponent,
   },
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options,considering that writing a service class could be a bit cumbersome i would suggest to use the local storage approach (#2), not less important this approaches are history agnostic:

1-Create a shared service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomService {
  data = '';
}

export class OneComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private myService: CustomService){};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myService.data = "Some text data stored"
  }
}
```

2-Use local storage

The purpose of LocalStorage is saving information on the client side and then we could use this information somewhere in project.

Code extract:

Instead of using LocalStorage directly in our Angular project create a wrapper class.

```
.
.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InfoService {
  constructor() { }

  public get name(){
    return localStorage.getItem('name');
  }
  public set name(value:string){
    localStorage.setItem('name', value);  
  }
.
.
```

Right now we have only one place which we will change. This class is much more easier to extend than add a new line of LocalStorage.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InfoService {
  constructor() { }

  public get name(){
    return localStorage.getItem('name');
  }
  public set name(value:string){
    localStorage.setItem('name', value);  
  }

  public get user(): User{
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  }
  public set user(value: User){
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(value));  
  }
}

export class User {
  public name: string = '';
  public surname: string = '';
}
```

Combination of Service and LocalStorage has benefits. Service class is easy to extend and change, that is save a lot of precise time.

Full source: [source](https://github.com/8Tesla8/local-storage-angular)